Electrical connections between battery and GND on PCB

I'm really new to electronics and circuit design, and I'm trying to design a PCB for some heated gloves. Basically I want to have the Arduino Nano control a MOSFET that opens and closes to allow current to flow through the heating element, which will be attached to the screw terminal. The temperature sensor will deactivate the MOSFET if the gloves internal temperature gets too high.
I followed a video tutorial to create the battery charging circuit, and I also added a buzzer that will activate if the Arduino detects the voltage across the battery is too low. The voltage stepper will keep the circuit at 5V (will probably use a 3.7 V 2000mAh battery, connected to the J5 socket pins).
One thing I am having trouble with is visualizing how the flags connect to each other. The battery charging circuit I based mine off of included both BATT flags and GND flags, and I'm wondering if, and how, they relate to each other. Do I need to have a place in the circuit where there is both a BATT- flag and a GND flag, like at the J5 pin socket? Also any other tips or corrections in my circuit would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for helping me out!
This is made on KiCad 8.
